# Meta Query Array Error 500

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, 500-internal-error

I have two CPTs – `Match` and `Player`. Each `Match` post entry contains details relating to a specific match (who played, scorers, etc.). This info is inputted via ACF Post Object fields corresponding with an individual `Player`. What I'm looking to achieve, though, is to generate on each `Player` post a total of how many appearances, sub appearances and goals.

To do this, I am using the following `meta_query` to get the total where a player started a match. The query is cumbersome, but it does the job. The problem I'm now having, though, is that attempts to generate the total number of sub appearances using the same query structure exhausts memory and returns an Error 500.

```
$args = array('post_type'  => 'match',
              'meta_query' => array('relation' => 'OR',
                 array('relation' => 'AND',
                   array('key'=> 'pl12',
                         'value'=> $playerID,
                         'compare'=> '=',),
                   array('key'=> 'si12',
                         'value'=> '0',
                         'compare'=> '!=',),
                   ),
                   array('relation' => 'AND',
                     array('key'=> 'pl13',
                           'value'=> $playerID,
                           'compare'=> '=',),
                     array('key'=> 'si13',
                           'value'=> '0',
                           'compare'=> '!=',),
                   ),
                   ...
                   array('relation' => 'AND',
                     array('key'=> 'pl18',
                           'value'=> $playerID,
                           'compare'=> '=',),
                   array('key'=> 'si18',
                         'value'=> '0',
                         'compare'=> '!=',),
                   ),
                 ),
              );
$subs = new WP_Query( $args );
echo "(".$subs->found_posts.")";
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

Using `functions.php` as suggested, custom SQL queries have provided a reliable and working solution to provide an output of total appearances, sub appearances and goals for each `Player` using the `Match` post data.

```
function get_player_stats( $player_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

$stats = [];

$stats['apps'] = (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT COUNT(pm.meta_id) FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE pm.meta_key IN ('PL1','PL2','PL3','PL4','PL5','PL6','PL7','PL8','PL9','PL10','PL11')
        AND pm.meta_value = %d
        AND p.post_type   = 'match'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
", $player_id ) );

$stats['subs'] = (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pm.meta_id) FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pm2 ON pm2.post_id = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE 1
        AND (
            pm.meta_key IN ('PL12',  'PL13',  'PL14',  'PL15',  'PL16',  'PL17',  'PL18')
            AND pm.meta_value = %d
        )
        AND (
            pm2.meta_key IN ('si12','si13','si14','si15','si16','si17','si18')
            AND ( SUBSTR(pm2.meta_key, 3) = SUBSTR(pm.meta_key, 3) )
            AND pm2.meta_value+0 > 0
        )
        AND p.post_type   = 'match'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    ", $player_id ) );

    $stats['goals'] = (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT COUNT(pm.meta_id) FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
            WHERE pm.meta_key REGEXP '^S[0-9]+$'
            AND pm.meta_value = %d
            AND p.post_type   = 'match'
            AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    ", $player_id ) );

return $stats;
```

}

Comment: Can you please clean up the question removing unnecessary "appreciate",  "this means", "I have a WordPress site". Just ask the question with no poetry, be dry as dust. Or else nobody will read.

Comment: WordPress does a good job many times: in my experience not when it comes to queries. Have you considered writing your own SQL query for this?

Comment: I had been wondering if this might be best done with an SQL query @kero, so I'll take a look – thanks.

Comment: @PeteHayman what is the value of "SI" (e.g. `SI1`)? Is it a Post Object field, or is the value a number of the player's total sub-appearances in the match?

Comment: @SallyCJ The value of SI is a number; it is the minute in the match at which a sub-appearance starts, so anything that _isn't_ `0` means a sub-appearance is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous answer (that I've deleted..), I suggested using custom SQL queries, which worked for me. However, since it didn't work (well) for you, let's try using this function:

```
function get_player_stats( $player_id ) {
    $apps = 0;  // Total appearances.
    $subs = 0;  // Total sub-appearances.
    $goals = 0; // Total goals.

    // Get all published `match` posts.
    $posts = get_posts( [
        'post_type'      => 'match',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ] );

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        for ( $n = 1; $n <= 18; $n++ ) {
            // Check if the player is $player_id
            $pl = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pl' . $n, true );
            if ( $player_id == $pl ) {
                $apps++;

                // Check his sub-out appearance.
                $so = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'so' . $n, true );
                $subs += $so ? 1 : 0;

                // Check his sub-in appearance.
                $si = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'si' . $n, true );
                $subs += $si ? 1 : 0;
            }

            // Check if he scored goal {$n}-th.
            $s = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 's' . $n, true );
            if ( $player_id == $s ) {
                $goals++;
            }
        }
    }

    // WP_Query was called; so resets $wp_query
    wp_reset_query();

    return compact( 'apps', 'subs', 'goals' );
}
```

If you have more than 18 players (in any matches), change the `18` in the `$n <= 18;` to the correct number of players; e.g. `20` as in `$n <= 20;`.

And here's how you could use the `get_player_stats()` function, which returns an associative array with `apps`, `subs`, and `goals` as the keys:

```
$stats = get_player_stats( $playerID );
//var_dump( $stats );

echo $stats['apps'] . ' apps, ' .
    $stats['subs'] . ' subs, and ' .
    $stats['goals'] . ' goals.<br>';
```

I hope this answer works for you, and let me know if you need any clarification (on any parts of the code). =)

Comment: I will check this out as soon as possible, thank you! When using a function as you suggest, should this go in `functions.php` and then using the `get_player_stats()` function code on the page(s) in question? I've never been fully clear on this when dealing with functions in this way.

Comment: Yes, add the function into the theme's `functions.php` file. Sorry I forgot to mention that part. :p And the function would then be available on any pages.

Comment: I've now tried this new solution, but with no joy :( – the function seems to break the code at the point of attempting the output. You can see from [this screenshot](https://www.boroguide.co.uk/images/screenshots/profile.png) how the profile should look (the 0s are placeholders for example) and [this screenshot](https://www.boroguide.co.uk/images/screenshots/profile-1.png) is what happens wwith this solution. I thought it could be due to use of `$player_id` in the function rather than `$playerID`, but that "fix" had no impact. Unless I'm missing something dead obvious?

Comment: No, it's not the variable name. Unless of course the function is defined as `function get_player_stats( $playerID )` and yet `$player_id` is used instead of `$playerID` in the function. Is it possible for you to share your code (or the code you've attempted so far) on Pastebin?

Comment: Try to rename the function? E.g. `my_get_player_stats` instead of `get_player_stats`. Because maybe there's an existing function with the same name. Or secondly, try to change the `get_posts( [ ... ] )` to `get_posts( array( ... ) )` - i.e. use `array()` instead of the short version `[]`.

Comment: I took out `'posts_per_page' => -1` and it's now showing something @SallyCJ. The totals shown aren't right, though. Using the original short version`[ ]`, the data for player **948** is 7 apps, 4 subs and 1 goal instead of 8 apps, 6 subs and 4 goals. [This is the function code](https://pastebin.com/ZENzezgh) and [this is how I'm calling it](https://pastebin.com/uygT2xAL). I also tried `array()` by [changing the function to this](https://pastebin.com/TZA0iqMM) but have since changed back. Is not including `'posts_per_page' => -1` limiting the number of queried posts?

Comment: As another example, player **943** should be 5 apps, 13 subs (and 1 goal) but the output using `[ ]` is 10 apps and 10 subs. Quite confusing!!

Comment: Yes, `'posts_per_page' => -1` means "query all posts", and if you didn't remove it, you'd probably get the correct values. Using `[]` or `array()` isn't the issue here, and you can get back to using `[]` — I asked you to use `array()` in case the `[]` was the one that causing the code to break.

Comment: I mean, try enabling back the `'posts_per_page' => -1`? And if the code is still terminating the page's output, temporarily enable `WP_DEBUG` and check [`wp-content/debug.log`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG) for any related errors.

Comment: I think I know why the function is breaking the page. The error message returned is: `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /www1/284/test.boroguide.co.uk/web/wp-includes/meta.php on line 846`. There are 2100+ `Match` posts; I experimented with `posts_per_page` of `1200` and `1500` (instead of `-1`). It breaks somewhere between those numbers.

Comment: The output (when it worked) sadly was wrong again, but that's by the by for the time being; player **948** showing 15 (9) - 4 instead of 8 (6) - 4. Given I got the correct `subs` value running a query in phpMyAdmin, I wonder if that same query would work on the front end?

Comment: In the case of that "memory exhausted" error, perhaps we should just try again with the custom SQL queries. But instead of updating the answer, in the theme's `functions.php` file, replace the *entire* `get_player_stats()` code with [this](https://pastebin.com/d7TqCfkc) (same function but different code), and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I'm now getting an output with the new function code (hooray!). The total `goals` looks right, but the `apps` and `subs` totals are too high. I think I know why. The `apps` total is the number of times a specific `$playerID` is in the fields between `PL1-11` and `subs` is the total where that `$playerID` is in the fields between PL12-18 and where SI12-18 `!= 0`

Comment: The totals the function code outputs looks like `apps` is counting all occurrences of a `$playerID` between `PL1-18`; `subs` all instances between `PL12-18` (from what I can tell). I'm unsure how to adjust the REGEXP to accommodate this. I've done a pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/CR1ME1km) of an `apps` query for one player that returned the desired total via phpMyAdmin if that helps explain?

Comment: Hey Pete. I'm glad to hear that, despite not everything works properly. :) And I think I was not fully aware of the proper criteria for counting the `apps` and `subs`.. sorry about that. I'll check your Paste(bin) and hopefully come up with the proper SQL queries.

Comment: Not a problem at all! I've not done a pastebin of a `subs` query as I've not yet figured out how to get it to pick out `$playerID` from fields `PL12-18` AND only count those instances where the corresponding SI value `!=0` :/

Comment: I just wanted to confirm these: 1) For `apps`, we check fields `PL1` to `PL11` only; 2) For `subs`, we check fields `PL12` to `PL18` only - and that `SI12` to `SI18` `!= 0`; and 3) For `goals`, we check fields `PL1` to `PL18`; is that correct? And if so, the `SO` fields are not involved in any of the queries, right? However, for the `goals` part, in my tests, there are players/`PL` where his `apps` and `subs` are both `0`, but his `goals` is `3`..

Comment: Well, I used the data you provided through the previous answer..

Comment: You are spot on, certainly for points 1 & 2. `SO` fields are to provide reference at the front-end only; these fields have no role in the query as far as I recall. For the `goals` issues, I'm not sure what the discrepancy in the data is here – but the `goals` output is correct as far as I can tell, so I can look into any errors with the data there.

Comment: Actually the `0` `subs` and `apps`, but `3` `goals` was due to a mistake I did in the [code](https://pastebin.com/d7TqCfkc).. sorry about that. But again, please try it out and let me know.

Comment: ...and that's got it! I made a couple of slight amendments to the function code, but the output is now present and correct. I'll post the code in my original question and up-vote your answer, as it has got me a solution to my issue.

Comment: I replaced the `$range` bit with a list of the fields to be included in the `IN` part of the query. I could see the logic behind `$range` and its use, but it didn't seem to want to deliver the output.

Comment: (I've just seen your update in the question.) So thanks for the upvote and for accepting the answer! Cheers. :)

Comment: No problem! Do you know if can I then take this code and rework it to call a list of `match` posts in which any given `player` has played (rather than count)? I did [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/bVSxq1Tn) to call the first, but it outputs the `else` value of 'No Debut'. I felt this related to the original question, hence why it isn't a new question :/

Comment: Hi Pete. Try this: `SELECT DISTINCT p.ID FROM wp_posts p INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID WHERE p.post_type = 'match' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND ( pm.meta_key REGEXP '^pl[0-9]+$' AND pm.meta_value+0 >= 1 ) ORDER BY p.post_date DESC` which queries all published `match` posts, sorted by date in `desc`ending order.

Comment: Or instead of selecting just the post IDs, you should select all the post fields (`ID`, `post_title`, etc.) - use `SELECT p.*` (instead of `SELECT DISTINCT p.ID`) and add `GROUP BY p.ID` *before* the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Using the second suggestion has done it. Perfect!